# Why do our emails sent out to our users have a via salesforce.com address?

Tags: email

I use “OrgWideEmailAddress” to send out email to our users,

In addition to an email template,
Everything works fine,
Except the email that reaches the user has our organization email + a via email as follows:
Myemailaddress@OrganizationAdress.com via ghfouh5jewe0jwgx.0rfs3df54zjsdf1xnu.d1d0v.a-hsdfmd5.fs31.bnc.salesforce.com

Other questions show that the "Enable Sender ID compliance",
In email administrator causes that,
But people still get the via,
Even if they uncheck that option,

Plus some articles say its important to keep that option checked,

How can I remove the “`via ghfouh5jewe0jwgx.0rfs3df54zjsdf1xnu.d1d0v.a-hsdfmd5.fs31.bnc.salesforce.com`”, from the emails that are received by our users?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's the way Salesforce is setup by default. If it wasn't there your emails would most likely get marked as Spam. So what you need to do is essentially whitelist the Salesforce servers on your domain you're sending emails out on. To do this add a TXT SPF record to your email domain with the following:

"v=spf1 mx include:salesforce.com ~all"

Once you have done that in your deliverability settings in the Salesforce Setup menu switch on "Enable Sender ID compliance" then that should be it.

**UPDATE:**
Just to update based on what @Tutul said. Salesforce now supports DKIM and is a better approach. It means that emails ONLY coming out of that Salesforce instance rather than ANY instance of Salesforce are validated. So it is more secure as well as a better spam prevention.

Answer (score 1):

Merely setting up SPF is not enough anymore. You also need to setup DKIM with your domains custom keys in order to remove the via headers.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Google Apps for your email, here's a simple solution using Email Relay: https://blog.groove.co/blog/google-apps-as-email-relay-for-salesforce-to-remove-via-disclaimer